# Confusing stack behavior in G77-compiled program

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, g77

I've got a mixture of C++ and Fortran 77, all compiled with G77.
It is mostly C++, but it calls the ODE-solver DVERK, which then calls back to a global C function to get the derivative (declared with `__stdcall`).
It's all been working fine, until I get a strange SIGSEGV.

I tracked that down, and it was because the `esp` was decreasing below its segment boundary.
The reason it did that is that DVERK contains the `**` operator, which internally is a function call with two double-precision values passed by value on the stack, for 16 bytes.
The function returns the answer, but then I see this instruction:

```
sub 0x10,%esp
```

which decrements the stack pointer by 16 bytes, as if it were putting the arguments back on the stack (?)
G77 seems to do this after every function call, and usually it does no harm because the stack pointer is unchanged.
However, in the case of `**` the stack pointer remains decremented, and if that code is executed enough times, the decrementation adds up until I get the SIGSEGV.
(If there is sufficient stack space, this problem doesn't appear because the return from DVERK cleans it up.)

I tried replacing the code `a**b` with `dexp(dlog(a)*b)`, but the same thing happens, except it happens in two steps, 8 bytes after `dlog`, and 8 bytes after `dexp`.

There must be something I'm doing wrong in setting up the calling conventions used by G77 vis-a-vis its run-time-library.
Expertise appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In this era, the way to mix C or C++ with Fortran is to use the ISO-C_Binding.  From C++, call with extern C.  In Fortran use (English language word) the Fortran ISO C Binding for the procedure being called.  This will cause Fortran to use C's calling convention (ABI).   Then you don't have to to understand compiler internals.    To do this, you will have to use a more modern Fortran compiler than g77, such as gfortran.    gfortran is fully capable of compiling FORTRAN 77.  Officially the ISO-C-Binding is part of Fortran 2003 -- you can write a wrapper in between the C++ and the existing FORTRAN 77.

There is a Stackoverflow tag that explains the ISO-C-Binding: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info

Comment: "Era"? :)  I've got the "extern C" part, which works fine. I haven't taken the plunge to gfortran, mainly because there's a ton of "technical debt" to go that route. But thanks for the info. I'll check it out.

Comment: There isn't much to understand in order to switch from g77 to gfortran.  Compiler options `-ffixed-form  -ffixed-line-length-none` will probably suffice to compile existing FORTRAN 77 code.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I would even just try switching to `gfortran` and leave the other changes if that didn't suffice. It quite well could.

Comment: But be aware just using the `iso_c_binding` module doesn't change the calling conventions. The `bind(C)` attribute does that. Usefel Fortran-C wrappers can be done even without that module.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not yet ready to dive into gfortran. I did find out the reason why DVERK was calling `**` millions of times - it was a bug in my code. That made the problem go away because if `**` is only called a few hundred times, it doesn't waste enough stack to run out of segment. But I do appreciate your answer.